# Handing N/A in Array Formulas

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, excel-addins, bloomberg

I want to figure out how to handle `N/A` in formulas that use arrays. I'm using the Bloomberg Data History Add-In `BDH` to get the latest `EX-DIV` date. But in cases where there is an `N/A` in the array, the output is `N/A` instead of the latest `EX-DIV` date.

This is the formula I am using:

```
=IF(AN6="","",INDEX(BDS(AM6,"DVD_HIST_ALL","StartCol=2","EndCol=2","array=true"),MATCH(MIN(ABS(BDS(AM6,"DVD_HIST_ALL","StartCol=2","EndCol=2","array=true")-$A$2)),ABS(BDS(AM6,"DVD_HIST_ALL","StartCol=2","EndCol=2","array=true")-$A$2),0)))
```

- `AM6` is the sedol
- `AN6` is a check for data
- `A2` is today's date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried encapsulating the entire thing with [`IFERROR()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/iferror-function-HA001231765.aspx)? It would become something like

```
=IFERROR(IF(AN6="","",INDEX(BDS(AM6,"DVD_HIST_ALL","StartCol=2","EndCol=2","array=true"),MATCH(MIN(ABS(BDS(AM6,"DVD_HIST_ALL","StartCol=2","EndCol=2","array=true")-$A$2)),ABS(BDS(AM6,"DVD_HIST_ALL","StartCol=2","EndCol=2","array=true")-$A$2),0))),$A$2)
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, please accept it as an answer so other people could find this and learn as well :)